# Ubuntu 16.04 Nautilus font problem

Tags: nautilus, fonts

New install of 16.04. 
Problem:   Straight after booting, open Nautilus and fonts are tiny - unreadable on screen due to small size.
Workaround:   `killall nautilus` - then restarting Nautilus. This restores fonts to correct size.

I have tried:
1. Various "Tweak" tools - all of which have an effect on font sizes but only until shut down.  On restart problem still there.

2. Writing and running a script to `killall nautilus` at boot - no effect despite log showing script execution.
3. Debugging the font cache
4. Uninstalling (purging) Nautilus and reinstalling - no effect.
5. I have checked through this forum for solutions but nothing I have found comes close to solving my problem.

Can anyone help me please?   Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I could confirm this problem on my side.

According to what Engineer77 suggested, `killall nautilus` could restore the correct font size, I added below line to `~/.profile`

```
(sleep 5; killall nautilus) &
```

This kills nautilus after 5 seconds when you logged in , works fine for me.